# Moving a movie strip into next free channel

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

If a script tries to move a movie strip to a channel that is full, does the script abort with an error?

Is there a flag I could use, to increment the strips channel so it moves the strip to the next free channel?

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a script tries to move a movie strip to a channel that is already full, it automatically moves to the next empty channel.

Comment: next empty channel?

Comment: Yes, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can aways use the "G" shortcut to grab along the Y axis in most editors, including VSE.

Just press G and then Y.